# Form submit function seems to only change a value for a split second

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list that changes value according to gold and silver spot prices. So having the ability to edit these always changing spot prices is crucial but i can't seem to get my form submit button to do anything permanently.

HTML

```
  <form>
    Silver Spot: <input type="text" name="fname" id="silverSpotPrice"><br>
    Gold Spot: <input type="text" name="lname" id="goldSpotPrice"><br>
    <button class ="submit" onclick="submitSpots()">SUBMIT</button>
   </form>
```

Javascript function the form button submits too (variables are called at begining of the javascript form)

```
    function submitSpots(){                                              
    silverSpot = document.getElementById("silverSpotPrice").value;
    document.getElementById('silverSpot').innerHTML = silverSpot;

    goldSpot = document.getElementById("goldSpotPrice").value;
    document.getElementById('goldSpot').innerHTML = goldSpot;
}
```

the function does change the form for a split second when I click it rapidly, but always goes back to the original HTML side preset.

```
      <th>Spot</th>
      <td><span id="silverSpot">SilverSpot</span></td>
      <td><span id="goldSpot">GoldSpot</span></td>
      </tr>
```

I.E. the silverSpot and goldSpot spots go back to "SilverSpot" and "GoldSpot".  after showing another piece of text for only a split second.

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate. Buttons are submit buttons by default and you don't stop the form submitting. Put the submit listener on the form's submit handler and cancel submit.

Comment: Add `type=button` to the `<button> element.

Comment: Scott Marcus that solved the problem! Thank you